# Hotmail SMTP Commands to Authenticate

Tags: c#, smtp, smtp-auth

I am using C#.Net and am programmatically attempting to authenticate against Hotmail so that I can send emails using:

- **Server:** smtp.live.com
- **SSL:** YES
- **Port:** 587 (tried 25 too)

I manage to successfully connect and get this response:

```
250-BLU0-SMTP395.phx.gbl Hello [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 41943040
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-TLS
250-STARTTLS
250 OK
```

I then issue this command:

```
STARTTLS
```

And get back a server ready response.

The problem now is authenticating. I **DON'T** see a `250-AUTH` capability, so naturally when I issue an `AUTH LOGIN` command, it doesn't work.

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote server advertises support for AUTH (LOGIN and PLAIN) in response to second `EHLO` issued *after* `STARTTLS`.

Plain text authentication (LOGIN and PLAIN) over unencrypted connection is not secure.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll give it a try when i get back home and will update my finding here. Much appreciated.